# Can POSIX/Linux unlink file entries completely race free?

Tags: linux, file-io, path, posix, race-condition

POSIX famously lets processes rename and unlink file entries with no regard as to the effects on others using them, whilst Windows by default raises an error if you even try to touch the timestamps of a directory which has a file handle open somewhere deep inside inside.

However Windows doesn't need to be so conservative. If you open all your file handles with FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS and FILE_SHARE_DELETE and take care to rename files to random names just before flagging deletion, you get POSIX semantics including lack of restriction on manipulating file paths containing open file handles.

One very nifty thing Windows can do is to perform renames and deletes and hard links only using an open file descriptor, and therefore you can delete a file without having to worry about whether another process has renamed it or any of the directories in the path preceding the file's location. This facility lets you perform completely race free file deletions - once you have an open file handle to the right file, you can stop caring about what other processes are doing to the filing system, at least for deletion (which is the most important as it implicitly involves destroying data).

This raises the question of what about POSIX? On POSIX unlink() takes a path, and between retrieving the current path of a file descriptor using /proc/self/fd/x or F_GETPATH and calling unlink() someone may have changed that path, thus potentially leading to the wrong file being unlinked and data lost.

A considerably safer solution is this:

1. Get one of the current paths of the open file descriptor using /proc/self/fd/x or F_GETPATH etc.
2. Open its containing directory.
3. Do a statat() on the containing directory for the leafname of the open file descriptor, checking if the device ids and inodes match.
4. If they match, do an unlinkat() to remove the leafname.

This is race safe from the parent directory upwards, though the hard link you delete may not be the one expected. However, it is not race safe if within the containing directory a third party process were to rename your file to something else and rename another file to your leafname between you checking for inode equivalence and calling the unlinkat(). Here the wrong file could be deleted, and data lost.

I therefore ask the question: can POSIX, or any specific POSIX implementation such as Linux, allow programs to unlink file entries completely race free? One solution could be to unlink a file entry by open file descriptor, another could be to unlink a file entry by inode, however google has not turned up solutions for either of those. Interestingly, NTFS *does* let you delete by a choice of inode or GUID (yes NTFS does provide inodes, you can fetch them from the NT kernel) in addition to deletion via open file handle, but that isn't much help here.

In case this seems like too esoteric a question, this problem affects [proposed Boost.AFIO](https://boostgsoc13.github.io/boost.afio/doc/html/afio.html) where I need to determine what filing system races I can mitigate and what I cannot as part of its documented hard behaviour guarantees.

**Edit:** Clarified that there is no canonical current path of an open file descriptor, and that in this use case we don't care - we just want to unlink some one of the links for the file.

Comment: "The current path of the open file descriptor" makes no sense. The file descriptor is stateless in the sense that it doesn't keep track of which path was used to get to the file.  If you are in a room with three doors, closing the door you used to enter the room does not make the room inaccessible to others, in the same way that unlinking the path you used to get the file descriptor probably doesn't delete any data.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Sorry, just realised you were referring to hard links. We don't care if deleting a file doesn't actually delete it. The code which deletes files only unlinks them, if other hard links remain so be it.

Comment: Niall  So what exactly are you concerned about?  If you want to unlink, then do it. There is no race condition.

Comment: If you want to ensure that some process doesn't change the file that a link refers to before you open it, use advisory locking.

Comment: As I explained in the OP, there is a race between when comparing inodes for equivalence from statat() and the unlinkat(). This seems too obvious for the Austin Working Group to have missed. I am worried I am missing something.

Comment: the `unlink` syscal takes a path and not an open fd or an inode because it operates on the path, not on the inode.  It simply removes the specified path.
I don't get which race you're referring to.  Maybe you're worried that some other process replaces the file you want to delete with another one, but for that to happen then the 'attacker' would have to put the file at that path, and if it's an 'extra' path to the file, then nothing happens, and if it can remove any other path, then it would be able to delete the file itself, no need to trick you into deleting it.

Comment: @Javier: It's not a question of malicious attackers, this isn't a security problem. Race conditions on the filing system are just the same as with memory. For memory we have mutexes, for the filing system we have lock files and advisory locks but these only work per file, not per directory hierarchy. If there were some way of locking a directory during unlinkat() it could be made race free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No replies to this question, and I have spent several days trawling through Linux source code. I believe the answer is "currently you can't unlink a file race free", so I have opened a feature request at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93441 to have Linux extend unlinkat() with the AT_EMPTY_PATH Linux extension flag. If they accept that idea, I'll mark this answer as the correct one.

Comment: It's been 4 years so you might not care anymore, but if you wanted to try again, I think the way to go is to have an `unlink` variant that takes a pathname and an fd and works similar to the atomic CAS primitive in your CPU: if the pathname points to the inode referred to by the fd, unlink, otherwise error

Comment: Unfortunately there is a race between the check of the path and the unlink. Another process could rename a directory in the path or the file itself. I believe the kernel must implement support for race free unlink, it cannot be emulated better than to the inode's parent directory.

Comment: I'm not suggesting emulating it (which is impossible). I'm saying if you were to add a new kernel syscall for race-free unlink, one with CAS-like semantics would be workable, as opposed to trying to discern the path from the inode alone like the bugzilla suggestion